# Chart.js Ionic 2 Angular2: Background color of bar graph not changing

Tags: typescript, angular, chart.js, ionic2

I'm using Chart.js to create a stacked bar graph for a hybrid app using Ionic2 and Angular2. I cannot get the background color or fill color of the bars in the graph to change. I've used every configuration/example that is given on [chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/), and I always get the default red and blue default(?) colors.

Here is what I have:

```
barChartOptions:any = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        categoryPercentage: 0.6,
        barPercentage: 1.0,
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        gridLines: {
            color: "rgba(255,255,255,1.0)",
            zeroLineColor: "rgba(254,254,254, 1.0)"
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
        display: false,
    }
};
barChartLabels:string[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
barChartType:string = 'bar';
barChartLegend:boolean = false;;

barChartData:any[] = [

    {
        fillColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: "rgba(10,150,132,1)",
        borderWidth: 5,
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], 
    },
    {
        backgroundColor: '#61ae37',
        data : [190,150,125,185,150,135,175]
    }
];
```

The issue is the `fillColor` or the `backgroundColor` fields in the barChartData object.

Other configs that I've tried from the documentation are:

```
data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
backgroundColor: [
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
],
borderColor: [
    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
],
borderWidth: 1
```

I also can't get the border color to change EVEN THOUGH I can get the border width to change.

I've also tried changing it with the rectangle configuration. No yield.

The original code I copied was this:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};
```

My best guess is that there is some default configuration that is taking precedence over my configuration. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I am using [ng2-charts](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) and their configuration is just subtly different. They use a `[colors]` field in the html markup where you add the colors in. So, what you do is create an additional object in your .ts file for your colors OUTSIDE of your chart options object.

```
barChartColors: any [] =[
    {
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        borderColor: "rgba(10,150,132,1)",
        borderWidth: 5
    },
    {
        backgroundColor:'rgb(97 174 55, 1 )',
        borderColor: "rgba(10,150,132,1)",
        borderWidth: 5,
    }
]
```

And in the markup it looks like this:

```
<base-chart class="chart"
           [datasets]="barChartData"
           [labels]="barChartLabels"
           [options]="barChartOptions"
           [colors]="barChartColors" <-----this is the kicker
           [legend]="barChartLegend"
           [chartType]="barChartType"
           [responsive]='false'
           (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
           (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">

           </base-chart>
```

Comment: This works for bar chart. Do you know how to change color for donut chart?