# How to change the default barchart colour in chart.JS and angular 7?

Tags: chart.js, angular7

How to change the default color, which is pink & blue to some other colors.

I know ways to set each bar a different color, but I need a user defined same color for all the charts.

How can I achieve this. ?

### html code

```
 <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

### Typescript code

```
this.barChartData.push({
          label: 'Request',
          data: requests, 
          backgroundColor: "#bcf5ec"
        },
          {
            label: 'Feedback',
            data: feedbacks,
            backgroundColor:'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
          }
        );
```

Here in image its pink & blueI need to change it to yellow & red

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `backgroundColor`.
Use an extra variable for `data` and `options` so you can access them easily.

I made you [an example](https://jsbin.com/yapodepaci/1/edit?html,js,output) where you can change the colors dynamically.

If you want to change them once at the start it's much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Added [colors]="barChartColors" in html & define colors in barChartColors.

Typescript

```
public barChartColors: any [] =[
    {
        backgroundColor:'#91ebda',
        //borderColor: "rgba(10,150,132,1)",
       // borderWidth: 5
    },
    {
        backgroundColor:'rgb(97 174 55, 1 )',
       // borderColor: "rgba(10,150,132,1)",
       // borderWidth: 5,
    }
]
```

html

```
<canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
            [colors]="barChartColors"
    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

[Chart.js Ionic 2 Angular2: Background color of bar graph not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870329/chart-js-ionic-2-angular2-background-color-of-bar-graph-not-changing/37885499)